# After running module, i got stuck with Python Turtle Graphics

Tags: python-3.x

Below is my code for drawing polygon based on user's input.
The problem was: i can't input anything. 
Because after executing module, the Turtle graphic came out and it got freeze.
Not sure which line is wrong.

```
import turtle
window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor('lightblue')
turtle = turtle.Turtle()
side = int(input("input number of sides"))
length = int(input("input length of each side"))
color = input("input color")

for i in range(side):
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.left(360/side)
    turtle.fillcolor(color)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script works correctly : https://repl.it/OAX6

It's not an implementation problem. check your host installation.

To fill the polygon use [`begin_fill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.begin_fill) and [`end_fill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.end_fill)

```
import turtle
window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor('lightblue')
turtle = turtle.Turtle()
side = int(input("input number of sides"))
length = int(input("input length of each side"))
color = input("input color")

turtle.begin_fill()

for i in range(side):
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.left(360/side)
    turtle.fillcolor(color)

turtle.end_fill()
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. It might be something wrong with my VM. Btw, how can i fill color inside the polygon?